# Distant supervision algorithms for NLP

Tags: nlp, unsupervised-learning

I am looking for **algorithms for distant supervision** (for Natural Language Processing applications). Can you indicate one applyable algorithm or method?

Comment: See this paper: https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/mintz.pdf

Comment: Thanks @kiner_shah, I had already taken a look on that one as a fundamental reference. My question is more towards the actual, practical implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice example that answers the original question, can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/real-life-code/2016/09/14/Relation-Extraction-Python.html).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is probably late for you but it may help others.

The snorkel project makes it easy to quickly learn Machine Learning models using distant and weak supervision:
https://hazyresearch.github.io/snorkel/